# How to seamlessly embed icon inside a clickable list item?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a mobile website project in which I need to make a list just like more of the mobile news app out there. When you click on the list item you will be direct to the specify news page. While by click on the button which is embed in the list, other action (like, share, etc) will be trigger.

I do have a pure html+css walk around for this which does the job, but I have some hard time to find a more seamless solution. My walk around demo is like this:
html:

```
<body>
<div class="fluid glcage">
<ul>
       <!-- row 01 -->
       <li>
       <a class="us" href="http://google.com">
       <span class="dimg"><i class="fa fa-medkit fa-4x"></i></span>
       <h3>dummy header</h3>
       <p class="desc">dummy description, dummy description, dummy description, dummy description, dummy description, dummy description... </p>
       <span class="source">www.cancer.org</span></a>
       <a href="http://facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg"></i></a>
       <a href="https://twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a>
       </li>
   </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
.glcage ul li{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 75px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
    border-top: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
    background: #ebebeb;
}
.glcage ul li a:hover h3 { 
    color: #7287b1;
}
.glcage ul li a:hover p.desc { 
    color: #757575;
}

.glcage ul li a:hover {
background: #efefef;
}
.glcage ul li span.dimg {
  background: #fff;
  max-height: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

and Fiddle demo here: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0q7tam37/8/) .
As you can see click on anywhere above the end of the "dummy description" and exactly on the url will direct user to google.com. But nothing will happen if you click on the empty area on right of the two icon.

PS:I really had a hard time to find a better way to describe this problem, so feel free to let me know if you got any idea to make the question more human readable.

Comment: If you want thinks to act like buttons **Use Buttons** [**Links are not buttons**](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/)

Comment: @Paulie_D More of links in my case, I did give a thought about using button to act as link though. In which case I assume I can just wrap <li> with <a> and using z-index to let button float on top of the whole list, have't give it a try though.